# How to put a point created by Epilog in a Legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to put a point in the legend, which is the easiest way?

My code is:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], Point[{1, 1}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x^2"}]
```

This gives me the legend of the parabola but if I add another entry it does not print the point in the legend.
What should I add?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: `Legended[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, Epilog -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], Point[{1, 1}]}, PlotLegends -> {"x^2"}], PointLegend[{Red}, {{1, 1}}]]`

Comment: Are you wanting one legend entry that is a blue line with a red dot in it or are you wanting two legend entries, one that is a blue  line and one that is a red dot?

Comment: I want two items in the legend, a blue line and a dot. So 2 legend entries. I triesd @BobHanlon suggestion and it works but if you have a bit of text the point is not placed in the mid of the blue line in the legend. I would like to have a result like in Matlab where everything is aligned

Answer (score 1):

```
plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> {"x^2"}];
plot2 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> {"A Red Dot"}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Epilog` puts graphics primitives after the plot is drawn. The legend has to be put together manually.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}
 , Frame -> True
 , ImageSize -> 400
 , Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point@{1, 1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Blue}
    , {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)", "Red dot"}
    , LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}
    (*,LegendFunction\[Rule](Framed[#
    ,Background\[Rule]GrayLevel[0.9]
    ,RoundingRadius\[Rule]4]&)*)
    , LegendMarkers -> {"",
      Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}]}], {1, 0.5}]]
```

[image]